# Bind JSON containing a dataset, to dropdownlist using JQUERY

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, wcf

I have a `JSON string` returned by a WCF service, which contains two tables in Data, as a string in it:

### JSON

```
{
   "GetYearsResult":
   {
       "Data": "{"Table":[{"holiday_date":null},{"holiday_date":1900},
                          {"holiday_date":2011},{"holiday_date":2012},{"holiday_date":2013},
                          {"holiday_date":2014},{"holiday_date":2015},{"holiday_date":2016},
                          {"holiday_date":2017},{"holiday_date":2018},{"holiday_date":2019},
                          {"holiday_date":2020},{"holiday_date":2021},{"holiday_date":2022},
                          {"holiday_date":2023},{"holiday_date":2024},{"holiday_date":2025}]
               ,"Table1":[{"holiday_day":1}]}",
       "Metadata":
       {
           "Response": 1000,
           "ResponseCode": 1000,
           "ResponseMessage": "Success",
           "ResponseTime": "18-Mar-2015 15:29:55"
       }
   }
}
```

I've tried to bind it using `JavaScript` as below:

```
function ConsumeData(data) {
        var response = $.parseJSON(data);
        $('#ddlYears').empty();

        //code to bind data to ddl
        var ddl = D.getElementById('ddlYears');
        var opt = D.createElement("option");
        opt.text = '--Select--';
        opt.value = 0;
        ddl.options.add(opt);
        for (i = 0; i < response.Table.length; i++) {
            opt = D.createElement("option");
            opt.text = response.Table[i]['holiday_date'];
            opt.value = response.Table[i]['holiday_date'];
            ddl.options.add(opt);
        }
}
```

How can I achieve the same with `JQUERY`?
Thank You!

Comment: What's wrong with just plain old javascript?  Anyways, if you did want to "convert" this to jquery, you'd just get the ddl like var ddl = $('#ddlYears') and then do your for loop and append elements to it like ddl.Append('<option ></option>')  with your text and values in there obviously.

Comment: Yes, u said right but, using `ddl.Append('<option ></option>')` didn't worked out... that's why i posted auestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the solution myself! :)
The issue was with JSON object that contains `GetYearsResult` as a collection of tables and to find those tables, we have to specify:

1. `data.GetYearsResult.Data` and
2. `data.GetYearsResult.MetaData`.

Below function accepts JSON data, dropdown name and binds first table of dataset to `drop-down list` and second one to `textbox` using `Jquery`.

```
var result = data.GetYearsResult.Data;
var ddl = D.getElementById('ddlYears');

function ConsumeData(result, ddl) {
   var response = $.parseJSON(result);
   var ddl = $('#ddlYears');
   ddl.empty();
   ddl.append($("<option></option>").val('-1').html('--select--'));
   $.each(response.Table, function (key, value) {
      ddl.append($("<option></option>").val(value.holiday_date).html(value.holiday_date));
   });
   $('#txtNew').val(response.Table1[0]['holiday_day']);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var $ddl = $('#ddlYears');
$("<option>").val(0).text('--Select--').appendTo($ddl);

for (var i = 0; i < response.Table.length; i ++) {
    $("<option>").val(response.Table[i]['holiday_date'])
                 .text(response.Table[i]['holiday_date'])
                 .appendTo($ddl);
}
```

Comment: Thank for answer but, It's giving error as, `TypeError: $(...).val(...).text(...).appendTo is not a function`

Comment: that's because you have removed `"GetYearsResult":   {` from `JSON` string